# HTML site having links to the other site to be opened in the same page

Tags: html

I want to create a pure html website. All the pages of this site will contain left side menu having the same content. This menu will have some links to other pages of different site. I want this links to be opened in the right side of the same page i.e. master page like concept. I don't want to use any other language other than html.

*From comments*:

***eg***. Suppose there is main.html i.e. your main page which have two iframes one is the left side menu panelwhich have the source page as say iframe_source.html. This iframe_source.html page have links to the sites like google.com or w3schools.com. On the right side of main.html we have second frame or iframe i.e. the container frame. Now I want that when the user clicks on the links to google or w3schools site those sites should be opened in this right side container frame.

Could anyone please guide me on this?

Comment: You could use `frames` which is deprecated HTML. Or use an iFrame.

Comment: The problem with iframe or frame would be, I have the page which will open in the iframe and will have some links to the other site. I don't have any idea that how can make those links to other site to be opened in the same page where the iframe is used.

Comment: `frame` is deprecated and `iframe` needs javascript

Comment: Your solution lies in iframes. Here is an example [ http://www.trans4mind.com/personal_development/HTMLGuide/iframes3.htm ]

Comment: @tvgemert opening a url inside an iframe doesn't require JS. You can set the target of an anchor to be the iframe.\

Comment: what about karnai kunai answer. that doesnt work too

Comment: No. That will not work for my purpose. You could see that in below answer.

Comment: The only way using only HTML and non deprecated features is by the use of an iFrame, that can be styled by CSS to achieve the exact same purpose as a frame. This however don't offer any control on how the links behave in the page opened in the iFrame, just as you don't have any control on that if you open it directly in your native browser window. There is absolutely NO WAY, even using javascript, to get a better control on this...

Comment: This can be achieved using iframes and it is working absolutely fine. You can check this in the below answer. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The src attribute specifies the `URL` (web address) of the `iframe` page.

An `iframe` can be used as the target frame for a link.The `target` attribute of the link must refer to the `name` attribute of the `iframe`.

[Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/WzxXmUxcX7KqGkfhuLIQ?p=info)

***style.css:***

```
.box{
    width:50%;
    float:left; 
}
```

***index.html:***

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

   <body>

<div class="box">
<iframe src="menu.html" name="iframe_a" frameborder="1" scrolling="no" width="100%" height="512" >
  <p>Your browser does not support iframes.</p>
</iframe>
</div>
<div class="box">
<iframe name="iframe_b" frameborder="1" scrolling="no" width="100%" height="512">
  <p>Your browser does not support iframes.</p>
</iframe>
</div>
</body>

</html>
```

***menu.html:***

```
<html>
  <body>
    <div>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="http://www.w3schools.com" target="iframe_b">W3Schools.com</a></li>
        <li><a href="https://www.bing.com/" target="iframe_b">Search Tool</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: what if the source file "demo_iframe.htm" have some link to say w3schools.com and I want that to be opened in the where this iframe is used i.e your main html page.?

Comment: @KinjalShah The `src` attribute specifies the `URL (web address) of the iframe` page. I tried this example in w3Schools editor. These work there. Here is the link [http://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_iframe_target ]. Copy paste this code on the link.

Comment: That is okay! But I want something different as described in above comment. This does not fulfil my purpose.

Comment: @KinjalShah you can't control where a website you have loaded in your iframe opens its links.

Comment: Is there any way by which I can achieve this?

Comment: @KinjalShah do you need something like this : http://www.trans4mind.com/personal_development/HTMLGuide/iframes3.htm , where  the first iframe would be on the left side like a menu and contains links in the same way as this website? Trying to understand what you are looking for.

Comment: No. This is not something that I want.

Comment: Let me give you an example of what I want to do. Suppose there is main.html i.e. your main page which have two iframes one is the left side menu panelwhich have the source page as say iframe_source.html. This iframe_source.html page have links to the sites like google.com or w3schools.com. On the right side of main.html we have second frame or iframe i.e. the container frame. Now I want that when the user clicks on the links to google or w2schools site those sites should be opened in this right side container frame. Hope now you get what I am trying to achieve. :)

Comment: @kurenaiKunai for what purpose is this used?

Comment: I meant should I post my query to the site you have suggested or it is meant for developing

Comment: I developed a solution for your query at this link. Are you able to see the example?

Comment: Sorry but I am not able to see it

Comment: I don't think so. I also modified my answer above. Trying replicating it in plunkr. I am using plunkr instead of jsfiddle coz in plunkr you can create different files/pages.

Comment: Could you please post your code here as I am not able to see it on Plunker.?

Comment: I added the code in my answer. See my above comment.

Comment: @kurenaiKunai Thanks a lot for your help and efforts! :) I have been stuck in this since long time. The code that you have given is exactly I wanted. :) Thanks once again!